# R: datasets missing from package

Tags: r, plot, dataset, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to access the "copper" dataset from the "fma" library in R, as seen in this following site:

https://rdrr.io/cran/fma/man/copper.html

Yet, when I try to access it:

```
library(fma)
plot(copper)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

When I try to view the data itself, it doesn't appear to be there it all:

```
copper

[1] "cop"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue

Comment: Same here. Have you reassigned something to the `copper` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem!

I went on the github page for this library: https://github.com/robjhyndman/fma

Then, I went here:

https://github.com/robjhyndman/fma/commit/7903ab59b5fdae0f1fb6ac40ac0c712780685815

The code to create the dataset was posted over here:

```
copper <- stats::ts(c(9.281972, 8.999700, 8.560122, 8.599723, 9.599666,
10.099527, 9.956961, 10.390599, 8.549561, 8.597523, 8.195346,
6.407771, 8.170265, 7.820450, 8.571122, 7.346990, 6.423171,
5.118516, 5.732342, 5.908350, 6.213942, 6.749665, 6.344848,
6.499735, 6.872430, 8.020219, 7.835631, 6.912252, 6.714024,
6.587298, 6.166861, 6.222963, 6.727444, 7.114221, 7.026437,
6.799827, 7.339070, 7.123241, 7.148102, 6.867590, 7.325429,
7.233906, 7.021377, 6.791687, 6.887611, 7.272187, 7.807250,
7.432354, 7.417613, 7.714186, 7.714186, 7.355351, 8.431856,
10.441201, 10.033084, 9.514742, 10.365298, 9.642787, 8.969999,
8.671006, 8.704228, 8.476298, 7.491756, 9.402757, 10.262554,
8.767810, 8.000198, 6.206462, 5.901089, 6.234623, 5.725522,
6.870230, 10.148589, 7.982157, 6.640541, 7.059438, 6.734925,
6.093377, 5.874468, 6.817428, 7.608581, 6.476194, 6.546817,
5.827826, 5.245462, 4.219118, 4.181057, 4.295021, 6.385550,
5.245462, 6.005594, 4.979250, 4.371145, 4.142995, 3.749838,
4.433407, 4.515471, 4.638676, 4.885086, 7.266027, 6.814348,
6.937553, 4.736580, 5.207400, 4.979250, 6.005594, 7.449955,
7.807030, 5.176819, 5.098935, 4.841745, 4.691698, 5.943331,
5.555455, 4.678498, 5.980733, 8.838213, 8.046180, 5.755663,
3.875024, 3.152733, 2.470484, 2.805339, 2.982006, 2.688954,
2.822499, 2.736476, 2.627351, 2.985966, 3.712217, 2.732515,
1.906601, 1.467682, 1.947302, 2.245635, 2.241235, 2.419222,
3.153173, 2.501726, 2.786638, 2.833940, 2.816339, 2.545068,
2.397661, 2.356740, 2.304377, 2.494685, 3.295299, 3.201135,
2.826679, 3.100811, 3.259438, 3.189695, 3.747198, 3.857203,
4.813803, 5.314985, 3.720137, 3.143273, 3.687136, 3.792300,
3.500128, 3.541490, 3.499028, 3.598692, 3.877224, 3.833442,
3.943447, 4.131995, 4.486870, 5.179459, 4.433407, 4.229459,
4.627235, 5.414209, 4.120554, 4.223738, 3.806381, 3.521909,
4.437587, 4.245079, 3.198495, 2.604910, 2.652212, 2.220114,
2.150151, 2.082608, 2.507666, 3.519489, 3.648634, 3.253717,
2.771897, 2.643192, 2.197893, 2.514706, 2.197013, 2.464104,
2.587309),s=1800,f=1)
```

Then, I was able to plot it:

```
plot(copper)
```

[image]

Not the exact answer - but I was able to figure it out!

Thanks everyone!